# Sharing files between two projects in one solution

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have one solution and two projects(server, client) and I want to share wrapper.h/.c between these two.
[image]

How may I accomplish this?

I have tried dragging wrapper.h/.c to both projtects without any success.

#### Update 2

Did as Adrian said, no success yet. 
Client and server are depended on wrapper. 
Building order: Wrapper, Client, Server.

1. Must wrapper.c contain a main function?

[image]

Comment: did you try "adding" the files to your project

Comment: Yes, but It still says that main.c cant find wrapper.h. Its strange since I can open wrapper.h/.c within the solution and their realtive path are correctly set.

Comment: Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wrapper.h': No such file or directory h:\labs\os\lab 2\client\client.c 16 1 Client

Comment: do they exist yet? Do you have permissions for that folder?

Comment: Yes they exit. I have full rw permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the wrapper into its own project, and have the server and client projects depend on it.

Comment: The same problem exists.

Comment: @Error404: Why did you also put the wrapper into the server and client projects?  My suggestion is to make a library project with the wrapper code and have the server and client projects depend on that library rather than trying to duplicate the code in multiple projects.

Comment: What do you mean by "library project"? Do you mean a "Class library"?

Comment: Right-click on your solution and choose Add > New Project.  At the dialog, choose Win32 Project and give the project a name.  Add your existing wrapper files to that project.  In the following wizard, select Application Settings and select Static Library.  Then make your existing client and server projects depend on this new library project.